# Unity Calling C# function from UnityScript file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, cross-language

I'm trying to run a function in C# from UnityScript. My UnityScript file has:

```
GetComponent("C#File").C#FunctionName();
```

But in the editor it's telling me that the function isn't a member of UnityEngine.Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 GetComponent<"C#File">().C#FunctionName();
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to put the "to be accessed" script in one of the folders thats compiled earlier.
> That does not only mean the editor folder, but also Plugins, Standard Assets and Pro Assets
>
> That way scripts of the other languages are able to work with it.
>
> The only alternative is not to access it directly at all and use SendMessage instead
>
> The least amount of trouble and headache is present if you just focus on one language instead of mixing 2+ languages